# Android- How to run a bash script from activity

Tags: android, bash

im developing an app that roots a phone using a shell script
however when i call the script it seems that script never runs
im using this code

```
void rebot(String command)
{     
    try{    
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh /sdcard/app/root");
    }
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

hope someone can help

Comment: Maybe you need to add some permission to your application ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    void rebot(String[] command) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It will ask for the permission ..just allow it.

Comment: nope...didnt work :(
now it dont show any errors but the still not running the script